# 3D Object in 2D Unity Project

Tags: unity, c#, lighting

Is there a way to bring 3D objects into a 2D project that is using the 2D Universal pipeline for rendering light? I have some 3D objects I want to bring in to the project I'm working on, but they just get imported as pure white.

Is there a way to import 3D models into a 2D game, and keep the 2D pipeline for lighting? I'l tried a few different shaders, but if they're not pure white they're pink. I would like them to have shading as a 3D object, and still interact with light and rotate on all axis if possible. If it's impossible to use a 3D object, if there was a way to at least have a 2D sprite taken from a 3D object, but still react to light as if it were 3D, that'd work too I suppose. This is what it looks like,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJeIN.jpg

I've also tried adding 3D lights as well, but to no avail. I'm guessing the issue is because of my 2D lighting renderer, and for the record, this is what this tree looks like in a 3D project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKCyd.jpg

I have since attached a custom shader graph to it that I made, it looks okay, but it still doesn't receive shading at all...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're using the default Sprite-Lit material on this object. Have you tried replacing this with a non-sprite material that will allow you to apply your diffuse texture?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have tried many shaders. I think I tried a good chunk of the URP shaders, all are either pure white or pink. I made my own shadergraph, but I'm not sure how to make it receive shading...